# How to handler any childrens (in any levels) of an element

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
<div class="fascia">
    <div class="elements">
        <h3 class="titolo"><a href="/link">Title</a></h3>
        <div class="desc"><a href="/link">Desc</a></div>
    </div>
    <a id="photo" href="/link">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

now I want to do an "alert" every time I go with the cursor hover every elements of `fascia`, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div.fascia").children().hover(function(){alert("test");});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ScgpX/)

You may want to pass filter selector to children method (i.e. `children("div")`) to avoid all children being selected (children and their children and so on, you will have multiple alerts for all children)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can just bind a `mouseover` event handler to `.fascia`. Because DOM events bubble up through the DOM, a `mouseover` event on a child will bubble up to `.fascia` and the handler will be triggered:

```
$(".fascia").mouseover(function() {
    alert("Mouse over!"); 
});
```

**Edit** based on comments

If you want the event to be bound only to children of `.fascia`, and not `.fascia` itself, you can use the `children` method:

```
$(".fascia").children().mouseover(function() {
    alert("Mouse over!"); 
});
```

Comment: No, I know how to do this! I need only for children(). So if an element have margin, I don't catch the handler...

Comment: @markzzz - As DanZimm said, you can just select the children and bind the event handler to them. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the jQuery [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method, eg:

```
$(".fascia").children().hover(function() {
  alert('on hover!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is something unusual like container div doesn't occupy space for children. Either height is lesser or having different positions. '*' could be used to target all elements like

```
$('.fascia *').live('mouseover', function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```